# Are there any objects that are not subject to garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In java(1.6 or earlier) , are there any type of objects that are not subject to garbage collection?

Comment: Do you mean that you have heard that some objects are not subject to garbage collection?

Comment: @jskchneider: According to an article i read,It specified "It is also possible for programs to create objects that are not subject to garbage collection"but they are not specifying about the object particularly.

Comment: there are no such object types. There are objects that can be pinned by native code (JNI references) but they are again checked by the garbage collector, just considered roots.

Comment: not guarantee about it............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All java objects are subject to garbage collection. However native resources are not directly managed by the garbage collector, some like window handles (JFrame) are freed by the garbage collector when a finalize() method is implemented others need manual resource management.

Also the jvm does not have to collect existing objects before it shuts down, this can cause subtle bugs like data not being flushed to disk.

Last there are extensions to the java spec for real time systems or smart cards which include unmanaged memory for performance and resource reasons. However this does not apply to the standard jvm.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have heard about weak, soft and phantom references. Check this
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by saying 'objects'. All primitive types except string and all data that was not allocated on the JVM heap (using operator new) are not subject to GC. Everything else is subject to GC.

Comment: +1: primitives can be in objects as well, however primitives on the stack are not.

Comment: `String` isn't a primitive type.

Comment: @Tom you are right on that, but my answer on GC still stands - strings are subject to GC.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the implementation even static fields are kept in an "object" (which you can see in a heap dump) which are cleaned up when the Class is discarded.

What you could be referring to is proxied data structures. These include GUI components, Threads, and direct/memory mapped ByteBuffers. In every case, the Object is on the heap, however there are data structure(s) not on the heap.